# Evaluate custom expression in R

Tags: r

I need to assign a matrix to a custom designed variable in R. So here is the matrix:

```
A = matrix(c(2,4,3,1,7,5),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

and here is the custom designed variable name:

```
G <- "Pakka"
```

Here I create the expression now:

```
G <- paste(G, "<- A")
```

and now I need to evaluate the expression so that the matrix `A` is assigned to the variable named `Pakka`.

```
eval(parse(G))
```

However, there is an error given by `R` saying

```
Not able to open file name `Pakka <- A`. No file of that name found.
```

Searing on `environment` is not giving me any clues. Please help!

Comment: You could also use the [`assign`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) function.

Answer (score 2):

The `eval(parse(G))` in the above question, has to be replaced by `eval(parse(text=G))`.

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Don't use `eval-parse` if you can avoid it.

Comment: If there is a don't, please let me know the `do`.

Comment: The `do` in this case would be to use `assign`. So `assign(G, A)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use `eval(call())` for this, or `delayedAssign`.

**Using** `eval(call())` **:**

`"<-"` is a special type of function, so we can hold it as an unevaluated `call`. Then when we're ready to evaluate it, we just wrap it with `eval`.  This was how this type of assignment was designed.

```
> A <- matrix(c(2,4,3,1,7,5),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
> G <- "Pakka"
> e <- call("<-", as.name(G), substitute(A))
```

A look at `e` shows that it's exactly what  we want to do.

```
> e
# Pakka <- A
```

Now we `eval`uate it, and `Pakka` is assigned to `A`.

```
> eval(e)
> Pakka
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4    3
#[2,]    1    7    5

> A <- matrix(c(2,4,3,1,7,5),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

**Using** `delayedAssign` **we can create a *promise* (unevaluated object) :**

```
> delayedAssign("Pakka", A)
> ls()
[1] "A"     "Pakka"              ## Pakka is there, but not in memory yet
> Pakka
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4    3
#[2,]    1    7    5
```